# Error:- "opencv_247.dll not installed in System"

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, codeblocks

I have a c++ program(using codeBlocks IDE to run) that require opencv2 to work which i have. Inside bin folder i have opencv_core2413.dll in my system and have set system variables but insted of 2413 version when i run my program it gives the Error "Program can not be started because opencv_core247.dll is not installed in your system". what should i do so that it searches for opencv_core2413.dll and not opencv_core247.dll.

Comment: Compile and link your program with OpenCV 2.4.13, rather than 2.4.7.

Comment: @DanMašek I am compiling it but how should i link it to OpenCV2.4.13 .. I have linked it to opencv2 folder and in it by default all dll files have 2413 sufix.

Comment: btw is it because of the yml files i am using for testing on new dataset .It may have happened that training was done using opencv2.4.7 and to test also i may need the same version. @DanMašek